# Can't access login page after password reset

Tags: login

After completing the WordPress reset password procedure I try to login with the new password but I get an error saying:

```
'Authorization Required. This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.'
```

The password has been changed but I have to use a different browser in order to view the login page and be able to login. Once this happens I can't view the login page even after deleting all the cookies. If I repeat the same procedure on a different browser the same thing happens.

Does anybody know what may be the cause of this ?

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't seem to be message coming from WP core. Are you using any additional plugins for security? Had you tried inquiring with hosting support about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be down to a number of reasons:

a) The browser you're having problems with is saving the old password and refusing access. This is why the other browser works when logging in with the new password. Try and reset the saved password to see if this solves the issue.

b) Your hosting provider has implemented an extra layer of security to avoid WordPress websites being hacked. Contact your host for more information.

You may also want to consider reading the following article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble

I would have suggested this in the comments, but I don't have a high enough reputation.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Glad it helped buddy. Was it (a) or (b)?

Comment: It was the second one (b)

Comment: (a) worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

In My case Removing Akismet plugin through ftp or cpanel helped me. Install it again once logged in.

Comment: Can you confirm this or provide any evidence so that it can be reproduced in a test environment? It's sounds strange that a kismet would cause this.

Comment: I confirm it and don't vote negative if you don't have knowledge of what i said is right or wrong. Akismet should be removed and reinstall again. what happend behind is a long story of security layer and can't be cover on stackexchange.

Comment: The down vote is because of the quality of the answer, please don't take it personally. This one sentence answer cannot be verified by others and other people may take advantage of that. Please add proper details & you'll get up votes instead of down votes. Also, before down voting, I've searched within Akismet repository for the error message, couldn't find it.